# imagemagick consuming all of ram then giving a core dump

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am doing a simple `convert -verbose -density 300 input.pdf -quality 100 image-%003d.jpg` which splits a pdf file into a series of images, one for each page. In this case, I am doing this on a large 800 page document. Not sure exactly what is happening, but imagemagick eventually consumes all of my system's remaining 16G ram and then core-dumps without outputting any images.

Here's what the form of the output looks like, assuming each `/tmp/magick-*` is one page being saved in temp files. Not sure what the first line does.

```
    'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r300x300'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-68824mpuDOrU2urYm%d' '-f/tmp/magick-6882498G4VzlCsOJk' '-f/tmp/magick-6882475lzlTzRy8pk'
    /tmp/magick-67235ClzIbj1qM7Yb290 PNG 1707x2633 1707x2633+0+0 8-bit sRGB 112324B 0.390u 0:00.208

...

    /tmp/magick-67235ClzIbj1qM7Yb291 PNG 1707x2637 1707x2637+0+0 8-bit sRGB 73753B 0.220u 0:00.320
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can I force imagemagick to do this in segments so it doesn't keep everything in ram?

(ImageMagick 7.0.10-9 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-26)

Comment: If this is not on a shared hosted server, you can edit your policy.xml to make use of disk in place of RAM. See https://imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml. Or you can try doing smaller groups of pages of the PDF file. Try the first page as `convert -density 300 image.pdf[0] -quality 100 image.jpg`. If that works, then try a range of pages as `convert -density 300 image.pdf[10-20] -quality 100 image_%2d.jpg`.  Alternately, try a lower density and/or a lower quality.

Comment: fmw42, this was a solution for me using the square bracket syntax for page elements/ranges. Didn't know the syntax, thanks.

Comment: See selecting frames at https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#input